# Python GET request for PHP page

Tags: python, get, ipv6

I'm trying to write a program in Python3 that takes a URL as input and checks its IPv6 reachability at this site: https://ipv6-test.com/validate.php

Here's what I have:

```
import requests

url = input()
resp = requests.get("https://ipv6-test.com/validate.php?url="+url)
print(resp.text)
```

The problem is this: while the results are different for google.com and amazon.com if you actually go to the site and test their IPv6 reachabilities, the GET request returns the same content for both (other than the URL difference). I've tried printing `resp.json()` as well but that raises a JSONDecodeError.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is, google.com is IPv6 ready, amazon.com is not, now for `resp.json()` the response you're getting is an html response and you're trying to process that as a json, that's why you get `JSONDecodeError`

The website has `divs` of failing/successing both set to `display:none`, and then simply does a request to "https://ipv6-test.com/json/webaaaa.php?url=" and updates the style depending on the value of `dns_aaaa`, (at least it looks like it), that explains why you're getting the same content while the answer differs

one way to do this is:

```
>>> url1 = 'www.google.com'
>>> url2 = 'www.amazon.com'
>>> goog = requests.get("https://ipv6-test.com/json/webaaaa.php?url="+url1)
>>> amzn = requests.get("https://ipv6-test.com/json/webaaaa.php?url="+url2)
>>> amzn.json()['dns_aaaa'] != None
False
>>> goog.json()['dns_aaaa'] != None
True
```

otherwise i'd try to **scrape** the site using some library like `Beautiful Soup`